# CSS menu moves on first hover only

Tags: css, menu, hover

I have a CSS menu here
http://www.salvationarmyqc.org/

When I hover the mouse over the menu, it shifts but only the first time a hover event occurs.

After that, it doesn't move.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I just noticed that in IE10 it moves every time it's hovered. In Chrome, just the first time.

Comment: Why oh why are you loading that entire menu as JS on runtime? You're **KILLING** your Google ranking by hiding all relevant links on your site, and probably causing this problem along with it.

Comment: I do this all the time. That way if I need to make a change to the navigation I just change it once. It's never causes an issue before as far as moving the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to post your css?

By the looks of it, you are setting a border width on hover which pushes the menu item down. You might try using absolute positioning, and adjusting the top height by -1 or a similar value.

for example your css might look something like.

```
#listContainer{position:relative;}
.listItem{position:absolute;top:0;}
.listItem:hover{top:-1;}
```

Im not sure why the entire navigation menu moves down in chrome without seeing your css.

Comment: the css is too long to post but it's here:
http://www.salvationarmyqc.org/css/nav.css

Comment: thanks. I replaced every instance of  
border-width:2px 0 0 0;
with
border-width:-1px 0 0 0;
and that did the trick.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

your #navigation is jumping from a height of 34 to 36px.  you could statically set it to 34pixels or put padding and margin to 0 for all of the li's.